# JS - check if element's declared style property is set in vh

Tags: javascript, flexbox, viewport-units

Say we have an element

```
<div class="vh-100">
 Content
</div>
```

```css
.vh-100 { height: 100vh }
```

How can I get to read that exact value `100vh`, because

```
var computedHeight = window.getComputedStyle(element).height; // will simply return the `window.clientHeight` value in pixels in this case.
var styleAttributeHeight = element.style.height // will return '', which is empty
```

To put it simply, I need to find a way to determine if the value is set in `vh` because the child elements of the example `<div class="vh-100">` have the box model broken and return incorrect `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` for some reason.

I need a simple solution excluding checking the `rules` in the CSS file.

Here is a [link](https://jsfiddle.net/wpvz5n3x/) to hopefully explain why I need this.

Comment: This feels like an XY problem: what do you mean by `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` is incorrect when using `100vh` on the element? What is broken about the box model?

Comment: _“Here is a link to hopefully explain why I need this.”_ - not really. Use your _words_, and describe the problem.

Comment: @misorude I think I've explained clear enough.

Comment: @Terry yes you are right.

Comment: @Terry if I were to use different techniques, for instance `min-height:100%;` and `display: table` and `text-align: center` and `vertical-align: center`, the box model would be working as expected, returning the "correct"/expected `offsetWidth` for the elements inside the target div to calculate the tootip positions presented in the link.

Comment: @thednp Can you show me an example where the calculation is off? From your fiddle there is no mention of these offset calculations and everything works as intended.

Comment: @Terry https://thednp.github.io/bootstrap.native/v4.html scroll down to tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

Directly no way, but i convert pixels to vh(1vh is 1/100  browser height). Here is code snippet, i hope it will help you.

```js
/*var z = getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName('deneme')[0],null).height.replace('px','');*/
/*var b = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);*/

//deactive variables for detailed usings.

var a = document.getElementsByClassName('sample')[0].clientHeight;
var b = window.innerHeight;
var c = Math.round((a / b) * 100) + "vh";
console.log(a)
console.log(b)
console.log(c)//it's your "vh"
```

```css
.sample{
 width: 10vw;
 height: 1vh;
 background:dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="sample"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but that's not the point. I need the declared value in the CSS file.

Comment: unfortunately no way getting vh value directly.

Answer (score -1):

if what you want is the unit of the height

```
yourElement.style.height
```

Normally it will return a string of height in it unit that you settled for the element (so `'100vh'` in your case).

Comment: This only works for inline styles, or styles that have been previously assigned via JavaScript. If the value comes from the stylesheet, and that is the case here, this does not work.